# Epson Scanner (WF-7720) is not found

Tags: drivers, scanner, epson

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Installing the printer driver for my all-in-one epson WF-7720 was no problem, but all efforts to get the scanner installed failed. I have followed several instructions on the ubuntuusers wiki, but still the scanner cannot be detected. Maybe it is because no epkowa driver was installed - and I could not find a way to install it manually.

Comment: Here are the drivers. https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Comment: The recommended epson drivers (imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-18.04-1.3.38.x64.deb) have been installed - that was the first thing i did. But still the scanner is not found.

Comment: Where did you get this package? The package at this site is imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-18.04-3.62.0.x64.deb

Comment: And please elaborate "not working". Is `simple-scan` working?